ffmpeg audio amerge with volume level adjustment and sidechain processing stopped working
I'm trying to merge my stereo background music with a mono voiceover audio with volume adjustment and sidechain processing to duck the music when voiceover is playing. This command used to work fine previously. Nothing has changed. But for my new voiceover files it is throwing below error. I've checked voiceover mp3 file properties in media file with old ones (that previously worked) and new ones, and they're exactly the same. Any help of suggestions please? I have tried to add various combinations of aformat filter, which hasn't helped unfortunately.
I could make it work with amix instead of amerge, but the output quality is quite bad with amix, so that's not an option either.
voiceover file properties:
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 2
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Duration                                 : 1 min 25 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 32.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 24.0 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 334 KiB (100%)


FFMPEG command:
    ffmpeg_command = [
        'ffmpeg',
        '-i', background,
        '-i', voiceover,
        '-filter_complex', '[1:a]adelay=5000|5000,volume=1.5,apad[a];[0:a]volume=0.7[b];[a]asplit=2[sc][mix];[b][sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.05:ratio=20:level_sc=1:release=500:attack=1[compr];[compr][mix]amerge',
        '-vn',
        'output.mp3'
    ]

Error being thrown now:
ffmpeg version 6.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers  
built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)  
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint\r\n  
libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100\r\n  
libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100\r\n  
libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100\r\n  
libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100\r\n  
libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100\r\n  
libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100\r\n  
libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100\r\n  
libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100\r\n
Input #0, mp3, from 'C:\\Kaushal\\video projects\\free music\\auto vid gen\\Bet On It - Silent Partner.mp3':\r\n  
Metadata:\r\n
    title           : Bet On It\r\n
    artist          : Silent Partner\r\n
    album           : YouTube Audio Library\r\n
    genre           : Jazz & Blues\r\n
    encoder         : Google\r\n
  Duration: 00:03:17.90, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 320 kb/s\r\n
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s\r\n
    Metadata:\r\n
      encoder         : Lavf\r\n
[mp3 @ 000001dc59edfd00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate\r\n
Input #1, mp3, from 'E:\\Y&H Source\\YHAI\\Classic black tuxedo\\solo (1).mp3':\r\n
  Duration: 00:01:25.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s\r\n
  Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s\r\n
Stream mapping:\r\n
  Stream #0:0 (mp3float) -> volume:default\r\n
  Stream #1:0 (mp3float) -> adelay:default\r\n
  amerge:default -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)\r\n
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help\r\n
[Parsed_amerge_6 @ 000001dc59f66c00] No channel layout for input 1\r\n
    Last message repeated 1 times\r\n
[AVFilterGraph @ 000001dc59f63780] The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_6\r\n
Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.\r\n
Error reinitializing filters!\r\n
Failed to inject frame into filter network: I/O error\r\n
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0\r\n
Conversion failed!\r\n"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Kaushal\Stable-Diffusion\vid_API.py", line 270, in <module>
    create_vid(image_dir, 30, channel="YH") # channel should be YBAI or YH
  File "C:\Kaushal\Stable-Diffusion\vid_API.py", line 121, in create_vid
    audio_clip = AudioFileClip(merged_audio_path).set_end(img_count * ( image_display_duration + transition_duration))
  File "C:\Users\KD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\AudioFileClip.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.reader = FFMPEG_AudioReader(filename, fps=fps, nbytes=nbytes,
  File "C:\Users\KD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\readers.py", line 51, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename)
  File "C:\Users\KD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 244, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    is_GIF = filename.endswith('.gif')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'endswith'



Start by upgrading ffmpeg, that's not the most recent version.

You're right @Destroy666. Looks like it doesn't work with this ffmpeg version:
ffmpeg version 6.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev
But the same command seems to be working fine with:
ffmpeg version 2023-11-28-git-47e214245b-full_build-www.gyan.dev

Good that it worked. But note for the future: always update your software before asking for support for it. No point doing it the other way round as this is not even worth answering now.
